# In browser script only click() first link, but not the button in the page opened by the link

Tags: javascript, browser, console

Hi guys I am trying to automate a process inside the browser:

First I have a search results with an anchor, so I take that element with queryselector() and use the method()click, then in the new url I do the same, just take the class of the link I need to open and use querySelector().click() and then the same on the third url. The thing is that when I put all 3 in a function with a setTimeout each and preserve log in my console the only step that shoots is the first link click and not the other 2.

I need to do all 3 things automatically to download a pdf when calling click() on the last url DOM element,

```
function download() {
   setTimeout(function() {
 document.querySelector().click();
```

}, 1000);

```
       setTimeout(function() {
     document.querySelector().click();
}, 5000);
```

```
       setTimeout(function() {
     document.querySelector().click();
}, 10000);
```

```
};
```

Comment: Is the page reloading?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.